# Upstream and DownStream Job on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Job B is dependent on Job A, when I trigger Job B, can the Job A starts first then Job B starts later.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Build Flow Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin)

Or you can trigger A and make B a down stream job for A.

Comment: This is an old plugin that is obsolete as per the documentation link.

Answer (score 0):

this is out of date - you should be using Jenkins Pipelines now.

I am using a declarative pipeline but scripted pipelines are possible.

If you want to kick off another job in a pipeline then use a build step.